# Text in the center of the box centering

Tags: c#

Is there a way i can make my text box's text into the center of the text box when its multi line?

My example is windows 8 login username text box if you haven't seen it Google it
I have not provided any example in code because I'm simply new to C#, I have researched it and it said something about grid? But I didn't know where to add it and I also thought it was for vb.net coding language

They all said things like

```
<TextBox Width="200"
     Text="Hello world !"
     TextAlignment="Center"/>
```

But i might sound dumb but I have never seen this in C#, am I looking at a different language? My app is below!!

[image: My app]

Comment: The code you provided is in XAML. Do you have any XAML file in your project?

Comment: No, I have no clue what that is

Comment: Are you creating a Windows 8 app or a classic desktop program?

Comment: Please watch an introduction to WPF (if that is what you are using),or Windows Store apps, on Youtube. They will show you what it is.

Comment: Im making a re-make of windows 8. Im using the base for a AdminCP for my website?

Comment: Is this an ASP Webforms project?

Comment: At some point you're going to have to decide whether you're making a desktop program, win8 app or website. What is it you're trying to make?

Comment: It is a windows form (.NET) with just picture box tiles and images for buttons for the login with a little bit of deaighn when you click the tile images form pages open. Its very simple as i cant find any tutorials for advanced ones?

Comment: Lets just say its a full screen app like windows 8 but its not a operating system it is a admin cp to edit my members

Comment: In that case, have you looked at the `Anchor` and `Dock` properties of your textbox?

Comment: I have added a picture

Comment: No i have not, Is that a good way to go? @Steven

Comment: Those are the properties that let you set the control's relative position. But maybe I misunderstand the problem.

Comment: Im trying to get the text of the textbox to the center of the textbox OR get to the right a bit? Not the textbox if thats what you thought

Answer (score 2):

In WinForms you can set `TextBox`'s [`TextAlign`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.textalign%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to `Center` like this:

```
textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
```

For multiline TextBoxes there is no property to set *vertical alignment*,but in `Form_Load` you can add some newlines to the `TextBox.`For example:

```
textBox1.Text += String.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat(Environment.NewLine, 5));
```

This will add `5` new line, you can change the count according to your `TextBox`'s height.

Comment: Just what i wanted, Is there a way to put it down a little as its a little high on the textbox? And not really in the total center? Other than that great answer! If this is solved ill vote the answer.

Comment: In multiline textBox I think you can add some newline's to the textbox .but there is no property for vertical alignment to do it directly.I have added an example